# javascript anonymus settimeout function queue values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

hi i have json array that i want to show every 5 second the next value

this code get the json from server and send json array to the function:

```
function myFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ws.aspx/GetQueue",
            data: "{'eventid':'" + eventID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg != null) {
                    var obj;
                    if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                        obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    else
                        obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

                    setHtml(obj);
                }

                setTimeout(function () { myFunction(); }, 5000);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);

                setTimeout(function () { myFunction(); }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my function after sent the array to it:

```
function setHtml(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
            setTimeout(function () {  $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + obj[i].QueueName + "->" + obj[i].name + ' : ' + obj[i].Queue + "</H1><br/>"); }, 5000);
    }
```

but the values inside the loop are undifined , why is it?
what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Which values? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, all are the answer except wirey for handle the json value inside loop.
the full answer is to add the element to queue like in this code:

```
$.each(obj, function (i, val) {                                
                        $('.Summary').delay(5000).queue(function (n) {
                                str = "<H1>" + val.QueueName + "->" + val.name + ' : ' + val.Queue + "</H1><br/>";
                                console.log(str);
                                $(this).html(str);
                                n();
                            });
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the loop inside the anonymous function:

```
function setHtml(obj) {        
    setTimeout(function () {  
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
            $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + obj[i].QueueName + "->" + obj[i].name + ' : ' + obj[i].Queue + "</H1><br/>"); 
    }, 5000);
}
```

Then read about javascript closures. In your version the value of `i` was its value upon leaving the outer function (`setHtml`), which is `obj.length`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the value of `i` is going to be equal to `obj.length` when the setTimeout runs.

```
function setHtml(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        (function(cObj){
            setTimeout(function () {  $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + cObj.QueueName + "->" + cObj.name + ' : ' + cObj.Queue + "</H1><br/>"); }, 5000);
        })(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that by the time your `setTimeout` function is called, the value of `i` has changed.  `i` will always be `obj.length`, and `obj[obj.length]` will always be `undefined`.  Instead, use `Array.forEach()` or `$.each()` to iterate your array:

```
function setHtml(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + val.QueueName + "->" + val.name + ' : ' + val.Queue + "</H1><br/>");
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

This wraps your `setTimeout` code in its own scope so that variables are not changed.

Alternatively, put the call to `setTimeout` in it's own function:

```
function setHtml(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        setSummaryHtml(obj[i]);
    }
}
function setSummaryHtml(val) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + val.QueueName + "->" + val.name + ' : ' + val.Queue + "</H1><br/>");
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `datatype:json` already so no need to do JSON.parseJSON.  By setting it to datatype:json it will return a javascript object so

```
if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
         obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
 else
         obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
```

can just be this

```
if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
         obj = msg.d;
 else
         obj = msg;
```

Also you need closure to loop in the setTimeout function

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  (function (ii) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.Summary').html("<H1>" + obj[ii].QueueName + "->" + obj[ii].name + ' : ' + obj[ii].Queue + "</H1><br/>");
    }, 5000);
  })(i);
}
```